# combine rows from fgetcsv arrays

Tags: php, html, arrays, csv, fgetcsv

Basically I have a csv file with order information on it, ordered from a website, containing invoice number, name, address, etc. I've used PHP to turn this into invoices. It looks pretty good but I'm completely stuck on one bit.

Here's the opening bit using fgetcsv;

```
<?PHP
$file_handle = fopen("orders.csv", "r");
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
$csvline = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
?>
```

In the csv file, if someone has ordered more than one item it appears on a new row with the same invoice number as the row before, but doesn't show any product in the first row of the invoice number:

```
100001,Bradley Manning,email1@address.com,Address,Product A,
100002,Mr Snowden,email2@address.com,Address,Product A,
100003,Dr Dre,email3@address.com,Address,,,
100003,,,,,,,,,,"Product A",
100003,,,,,,,,,,"Product B",
100003,,,,,,,,,"Product C",
```

The PHP takes these values (eg. $csvline[0] for the invoice number) and puts them in a nice printable html file. But I need to be able to get the rows beginning with the same invoice number onto the same html table (in the cell below the first ordered product).

Any suggestions for my pretty awfully worded problem would be very much appreciated!

Ps. Here's the php / html snippet:

```
<?php
$exvat = ($csvline[15] / 1.2);
$exvatrounded = number_format($exvat, 2, '.', '');
?>
<div class="t2 th">Description</div>
<div class="t3 th">Unit Price</div>
<div class="t4 th">Quantity</div>
<div class="t5 th">VAT Rate</div>
<div class="t6 th">Amount</div>
<div class="even">
<div class="t2 td"><?php echo $csvline[12]; ?></div>
<div class="t3 td">&pound;<?php echo $exvatrounded; ?></div>
<div class="t4 td"><?php echo $csvline[14]; ?></div>
<div class="t5 td"><?php echo $csvline[16]; ?></div>
<div class="t6 td">&pound;<?php echo $csvline[20]; ?></div>
</div>
<div class="odd">
<div class="t2 td">MORE PRODUCT LINES??????????????????</div>
<div class="t3 td">&pound;AMOUNT</div>
<div class="t4 td">QUANTITY</div>
<div class="t5 td">VAT</div>
<div class="t6 td">&pound;TOTAL AMOUNT</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***WARNING*** Your csv is not normalized - so getting it to work will be nearly impossible with the current csv layout.

Use the invoice number as the `key` to an `array`, then loop through the `array` in your output..

```
$file_handle = fopen("orders.csv", "r");
$orders = array();
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $csvline = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    $orders[$csvline[0]][] = $csvline;
}
//print_r($orders);
```

Builds the array:

```
Array
(
    [100001] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 100001
                    [1] => Bradley Manning
                    [2] => email1@address.com
                    [3] => Address
                    [4] => Product A
                    [5] => 
                )

        )

    [100002] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 100002
                    [1] => Mr Snowden
                    [2] => email2@address.com
                    [3] => Address
                    [4] => Product A
                    [5] => 
                )

        )

    [100003] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 100003
                    [1] => Dr Dre
                    [2] => email3@address.com
                    [3] => Address
                    [4] => 
                    [5] => 
                    [6] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 100003
                    [1] => 
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                    [4] => Product A
                    [5] => 
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 100003
                    [1] => 
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                    [4] => Product B
                    [5] => 
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 100003
                    [1] => 
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                    [4] => Product C
                    [5] => 
                )

        )

)
```

Using this CSV(normalized)

```
100001,Bradley Manning,email1@address.com,Address,Product A,
100002,Mr Snowden,email2@address.com,Address,Product A,
100003,Dr Dre,email3@address.com,Address,,,
100003,,,,"Product A",
100003,,,,"Product B",
100003,,,,"Product C",
```

Also, I would recommend using `tables` for tabular data instead of `divs`

To use this in your `HTML`

```
<?php foreach($orders as $order_id => $products) { ?> 
    <div class="t2 th">Description</div>
    <div class="t3 th">Unit Price</div>
    <div class="t4 th">Quantity</div>
    <div class="t5 th">VAT Rate</div>
    <div class="t6 th">Amount</div>
    <?php foreach($products as $product) { ?> 
    <div class="even">
        <div class="t2 td"><?php echo $product[4] ?></div>
        <div class="t3 td">&pound;</div>
        <div class="t4 td"></div>
        <div class="t5 td"></div>
        <div class="t6 td"></div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Just one more thing (completely new to this all!), how would I then use that in the php/html?